# Running a command before the Rails server starts under Apache

Tags: configuration, ruby-on-rails, apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I'm currently running Apache with Passenger and a Rails 3.1 application.
In my environment setup, I need to start sunspot - `rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production` - before I run the server. Since the server starts auto-magically when Apache starts, I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

How can I run a list of commands before the Rails server starts?

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS 10.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) config (or [install Solr with Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat)) to start Solr use a stanza like below:

```
start on starting apache2
```

This makes Solr will be started before Apache.

Comment: What do you mean?